# Can't use fdopen with mkstemp

Tags: python, temp, temporary-files

I am not able write to a file opened as `rw` by `fdopen` from the handle returned by `mkstemp`.

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> import os
>>> a = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> b = os.fdopen(a[0], "rw")
>>> b
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rw' at 0x7f81ea669f60>
>>> b.write("foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>>
```

Curiously, I can read from a file opened `rw`:

```
>>> g = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> h = os.fdopen(g[0], "rw")
>>> h.read()
''
```

If I open the file in one mode or the other then things are just fine:

```
>>> c = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> d = os.fdopen(c[0], "r")
>>> d
<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'r' at 0x2380540>
>>> d.read()
''
>>> e = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> f = os.fdopen(e[0], "w")
>>> f.write("foo")
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rw` is not a valid mode.

If you want to open the file with updaing mode (reading/writing), use `w+` or `r+` mode.

(See [`open` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): `mode` parameter of `os.fdopen` is same as `open`.)

Comment: of course... *facepalm*. Thanks for your help. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.